# Unable to read WCS from SDSS co-added Stripe 82 fits image

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I try to read the World Coordinate System (WCS) from a FITS file using satrapy and this code:

```
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.io import fits
data = 'file.fits'    
hdu = fits.open(data)
w = WCS(hdu[0].header)
```

I get the error:

```
WARNING: FITSFixedWarning: RADECSYS= 'ICRS ' 
RADECSYS is non-standard, use RADESYSa. [astropy.wcs.wcs]
```

The header file is:

```
SIMPLE  =                    T                                                  
BITPIX  =                  -32                                                  
NAXIS   =                    2                                                  
NAXIS1  =                 2048                                                  
NAXIS2  =                 1489                                                  
RADECSYS= 'ICRS    '                                                            
CTYPE1  = 'DEC--TAN'                                                            
CTYPE2  = 'RA---TAN'                                                            
CUNIT1  = 'deg     '                                                            
CUNIT2  = 'deg     '                                                            
CRPIX1  = 1.02500000000000E+03                                                  
CRPIX2  = 7.45000000000000E+02                                                  
CRVAL1  = 7.34210000000000E-01                                                  
CRVAL2  = 2.49604300000000E+01                                                  
CD1_1   = 1.09999999400000E-04                                                  
CD2_2   = 1.09999999400000E-04                                                  
CD1_2   = 0.00000000000000E+00                                                  
CD2_1   = 0.00000000000000E+00                                                  
COADD_0 = 'fpCs-002570-i5-0112.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_1 = 'fpCs-002570-i5-0113.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_2 = 'fpCs-002650-i5-0142.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_3 = 'fpCs-002650-i5-0143.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_4 = 'fpCs-002677-i5-0142.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_5 = 'fpCs-002677-i5-0143.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_6 = 'fpCs-002700-i5-0032.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_7 = 'fpCs-002700-i5-0033.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_8 = 'fpCs-002728-i5-0579.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_9 = 'fpCs-002728-i5-0580.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_10= 'fpCs-002738-i5-0084.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_11= 'fpCs-002738-i5-0085.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_12= 'fpCs-002820-i5-0032.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_13= 'fpCs-002820-i5-0033.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_14= 'fpCs-002855-i5-0038.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_15= 'fpCs-002855-i5-0039.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_16= 'fpCs-002873-i5-0075.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_17= 'fpCs-002873-i5-0076.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_18= 'fpCs-003362-i5-0033.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_19= 'fpCs-003362-i5-0034.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_20= 'fpCs-003362-i5-0035.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_21= 'fpCs-003384-i5-0535.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_22= 'fpCs-003384-i5-0536.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_23= 'fpCs-004128-i5-0289.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_24= 'fpCs-004128-i5-0290.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_25= 'fpCs-004157-i5-0042.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_26= 'fpCs-004157-i5-0043.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_27= 'fpCs-004198-i5-0528.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_28= 'fpCs-004198-i5-0529.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_29= 'fpCs-004207-i5-0538.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_30= 'fpCs-004207-i5-0539.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_31= 'fpCs-004868-i5-0374.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_32= 'fpCs-004868-i5-0375.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_33= 'fpCs-004874-i5-0587.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_34= 'fpCs-004874-i5-0588.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_35= 'fpCs-004895-i5-0202.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_36= 'fpCs-004895-i5-0203.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_37= 'fpCs-004905-i5-0168.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_38= 'fpCs-004905-i5-0169.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_39= 'fpCs-004933-i5-0529.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_40= 'fpCs-004933-i5-0530.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_41= 'fpCs-004948-i5-0109.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_42= 'fpCs-004948-i5-0110.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_43= 'fpCs-005566-i5-0395.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_44= 'fpCs-005566-i5-0396.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_45= 'fpCs-005603-i5-0614.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_46= 'fpCs-005603-i5-0615.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_47= 'fpCs-005633-i5-0582.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_48= 'fpCs-005633-i5-0583.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_49= 'fpCs-005642-i5-0242.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_50= 'fpCs-005642-i5-0243.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_51= 'fpCs-005658-i5-0069.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_52= 'fpCs-005658-i5-0070.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_53= 'fpCs-005765-i5-0161.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_54= 'fpCs-005765-i5-0162.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_55= 'fpCs-005770-i5-0548.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_56= 'fpCs-005770-i5-0549.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_57= 'fpCs-005777-i5-0013.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_58= 'fpCs-005777-i5-0014.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_59= 'fpCs-005781-i5-0546.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_60= 'fpCs-005781-i5-0547.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_61= 'fpCs-005792-i5-0587.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_62= 'fpCs-005792-i5-0588.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_63= 'fpCs-005792-i5-0589.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_64= 'fpCs-005800-i5-0568.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_65= 'fpCs-005800-i5-0569.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_66= 'fpCs-005813-i5-0605.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_67= 'fpCs-005813-i5-0606.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_68= 'fpCs-005823-i5-0572.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_69= 'fpCs-005823-i5-0573.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_70= 'fpCs-005898-i5-0610.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_71= 'fpCs-005898-i5-0611.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_72= 'fpCs-005918-i5-0587.resamp.fits'                                     
COADD_73= 'fpCs-005918-i5-0588.resamp.fits'
```

I have compared this to other WCS in header files and it does look different, but I am sure how to fix things. Also I am unsure how to use `RADESYSa` rather then `RADECSYS`. There does not seem to be any documentation that I can find. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the keyword header should be `RADESYS` not `RADECSYS` according to the FITS standard (please report this to the people who made this FITS file). To avoid the warning, you can do:

```
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.io import fits
data = 'file.fits'    
hdu = fits.open(data)
hdu[0].header.rename_keyword('RADECSYS', 'RADESYS')
w = WCS(hdu[0].header)
```

Comment: To add, the OP called this an "error", it is just a warning that the file is using this old incorrect format. It might be worth rewording that message somewhat since it confuses users reading files like this that they didn't create...